# How to move comments section out of its parent div

Tags: 8, theming

How can we move or override the placement of the comments in a node. Usually the comment section is placed inside its content div. My aim is to place this comment section out of its parent div which is usually the node content.

```
<div class="content">
 <div property="schema:text" ...>
    <p>
        Some Node Contents ...
    </p>
 </div>
 <section rel="schema:comment" ...> <!--move this comment section from here -->
    <h2>Add new comment</h2>
    <span data-big-pipe-placeholder-id="..."></span>
 </section>
</div>
<!-- to here -->
```

I have my template overrides

- field--comment.html.twig
- comment.html.twig
- page.html.twig

Inside themes/contrib/mytheme/templates

Answer (score 3):

Depending on which container you want to escape, you need to use either `node.html.twig` (recommended) or `page.html.twig` (harder, unlike node you can't use `{{ content.field_comment }}` in page).

If you are using `node.html.twig` (or somehting like `node--BUNDLENAME.html.twig`) and you manually render `{{ content.field_comment }}`, then you can avoid double-rendering of comments by rendering the "normal" content using the without filter `{{ content|without('field_comment') }}`